# Security in Play 2.0

Tags: playframework

I cant see any reference to security in play 2.0, isnt there built in support for it as in Play 1.X ?

also see question on play 2.0 forum (but not answered there)
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/security/play-framework/YHhpAXAsHzE/7g4XrIFsIV0J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no documentation for it yet (that I can find), but you can look at the Zen Tasks sample app for an idea of how to implement it.

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks

Comment: thanks, that solved it. I was looking for a login sample in the samples folder, but did find it before now, didnt look proper enough first time I see now

Comment: btw, a quick follow up question, how can I check if a user is authenticated in the scala templates? want to do something like this:
if(authenticated){
      show admin menu point
}

Comment: Basically you could just declare a variable in your view/template and pass it in from the controller (either an `isAuthenticated` flag or a whole `User` object). I'd keep looking through that sample project. That's what they did on the main.scala.html template. You would just add some @if logic for your admin stuff.